# Socket communication problem with C# server

Tags: c#, c++, tcp, boost-asio

I'm make this TCP server in C# (UWP App in Win 10/11):

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1]; //IP v4 address
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 21234);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Wait on: " + localEndPoint.ToString());
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                           SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

// Bind the socket to the local endpoint and
// listen for incoming connections.  
try
{
 listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
 listener.Listen(100);
 // Start listening for connections.  
 while (true)
 {
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Wait for a connection request...");
   Socket handler = listener.Accept();
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connection Request arrived!");
 }//while
}//try
//...
```

and I have this client, written in C++ with boost::asio libraries:

```
using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;

boost::asio::io_context io_context;
tcp::resolver* resolver;
tcp::socket* socket_;
   resolver = new tcp::resolver(io_context);
   socket_ = new tcp::socket(io_context);
   try
   {
    boost::asio::connect(*socket_, resolver->resolve("localhost", "21234"));
   
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
    std::cerr << "Connect Exception--->>" << e.what() <<  std::endl;
   }
```

Ok, I obtain an exception from client:"Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato"("Unable to establish connection. Incorrect response from the connected party after the time interval or no response from the connected host").

I think that the wrong in the server because I tried successfully with a C++ boost::asio client and it work.

Where is wrong?

Comment: This kind of a mystery is very easy to solve on Linux: run the client and use `strace` to see its syscalls. This will determine whether the client is trying to connect to the correct port, and what exactly happens that results in a failed connection, and this will serve to provide some clues as to where to look next, for the actual reason. Perhaps you want to look into what similar tools are available to you on MS-Windows, if any.

Comment: Can you change `IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 21234);` to `IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 21234);` any verify whether it changes the behaviour or not?

Comment: No, I haven't any behaviour difference.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I am using WireShark,  there are several excange beetwen client/server and I do not known how to isolate the problem.

Comment: Perhaps looking at what those "exchanges" are, exactly, will be helpful? The traditional TCP handshake is C:SYN, S:SYN/ACK, C:ACK. I'm confident that Wireshark shows these kinds of low-level details of each packet.

Comment: Are you sure `AddressList[1]` contains an IPv4 address? Wouldn't it be better any way to walk `AddressList` and get the first IPv4 address?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I should check it. But I sure that first excange is direct to ::1 address (it is a IPv6 Address) but I specified explicitally a v4 IP address!

Comment: @rturrado: Yes, the AddressList[1] is a v4 format IP address (127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0)

Comment: It has to do with the index : ipHostInfo.AddressList[1].  Most machine today have IPV6 as index zero and IPV4 as index 1.  Your machine may be different.

Comment: @jdweng: I also try directly with:

 IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
 IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 21234);

Comment: The endpoint cannot be the loopback IP.  You can try the IP of the machine which is what AddressList[] returns when you use the correct index.  Display what index 0 and 1 returns.

Comment: @jdweng: Ok, I'm not using the loopback address anymore and I'm getting the endpoint IP address with:
`IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());`

AddressList[2]display correctly the IP address of endpoint.

But in this case the client doesn't even find the server ("Unable to establish connection. Persistent rejection of the target computer")

Comment: Local host is defined in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.  Different PCs have the file defined different and may work on one machine and not another.  When making a connection on same machine the client and server can't use same socket.  So client and server must use different IP addresses.  Best way is for server to use loopback 127.0.0.1 and client connect to IP of machine.  Using Local host you may end up having client and server using same IP address.

Comment: As I had already written, with two identical addresses (localhost), there is a partial communication between client and server so this would not seem to be the problem.

But I tried as you suggest: 127.0.0.1 for the server and 192.168.56.1 (or 192.168.43.178 for the WiFi interface) for the client.

But even then it doesn't see the server at all.

Anyway I don't understand why it works with the C++ client and with the same client/server address. On the C ++ client, however, I don't have to specify any endpoint addresses (it's implicit).